# How can I start an MSYS2 console on cmd in current directory?

Tags: msys2

I installed MSYS2, but I can't run `msys2` console on `cmd` in current directory.

This is what I tried in `cmd` console:

```
cd path/to/mypath
msys2 -mingw64
```

The `mingw64` console does not run on `path/to/mypath` directory but in its own default path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit `msys2.ini`, `mingw32.ini`, or `mingw64.ini` and add this line to it:

```
CHERE_INVOKING=1
```

More information is in the [README of msys2-launcher](https://github.com/elieux/msys2-launcher).

Comment: Interesting solution, I'm still struggling with whether it's better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

As [I found out by reading`c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -help`](https://superuser.com/a/1835295/391675), you can start any `MSYS2` environment in the current folder by passing the `-here` switch.

Since I currently prefer the `UCRT64` environment, the following batch file (`msys.cmd`) makes my life easier that I have placed it in a folder that is in my Windows `%PATH%`:

```
set MSYSTEM=UCRT64
c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd %*
```

It's not hard to remember and pass the `-here` switch when needed, it also supports overriding the default environment by adding arguments like `-mingw64` etc.